# Space Vector Modulation Clarification

Tags: microcontroller, pwm

I am studying space vector modulation but every time i read i get confused. I hope i will get some clarification here. I am referring to the following document [SVPWM Document](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2014/WCE2014_pp253-258.pdf)

I am mainly referring to the Figure 24 to 29 pwm waveforms. Fig 24 says first changes in voltage combination. What that statement exactly means? Why should it be (100) and (110) I know 000 and 111 null vectors and we have to apply for some time. Similarly what is second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth changes in voltage combinations? And the Table III 
[image: Voltage combinations] how it is arrived?

Comment: The document is surprising clear and I know nothing of this business. Only changing one half-H at a time, having only three half-H bridges, there are only three possible "first changes" you can make. Having made one of those three choices, there are only two remaining ways to go. Everything else is determined from there. So that's six possible paths. Direction of motion is something that comes to mind about why one way, or another. But your question isn't clear enough for me to know what else to look for here.

Comment: There seems to be some slight English problems in the paper. It seems like Fig. 24, Table III row 1, and Fig. 30, (and so on) essentially convey the same information: The states that the power transistors are cycled through.

Comment: If you look at Table III why 1 is given 100 110 just it was random? or 1 could have been 100 101?

Comment: the voltage change bits (001,011... etc) follow `Gray code` ... only one bit changes at a time ... it prevents race conditions where intermediate values could occur briefly if more than one bit changed at the same time